# OSX implementation of WinBoard / XBoard?

Tags: software

Is there a Mac OSX implementation (or equivalent) of WinBoard / XBoard?

Comment: xboard can be compiled under OS X if you install XCode (to get gcc) and an X11 implementation (to get the libraries).  I have used it for years.  You will need timeseal if playing online on e.g. FICS.

Comment: Not an answer, but another OSX chess (the only?) which is still supported Kibitz. The version on GitHub is the latest, with the latest commit today.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Jin](http://www.jinchess.com/) seems like a good option.

Works well on OSX 10.8, and compatible with other platforms as well.

Answer (score 6):

You can technically still use XBoard, but you will need to install X11 from MacPorts, since IIRC Apple no longer ships it.

Julien Marcel has a collection of [well-compiled OS X chess engines](http://julien.marcel.free.fr/macchess/) (which do *not* require emulation).

As for not having a ChessBase client, [HIARCS Chess Explorer](http://www.hiarcs.com/mac-chess-explorer.htm) does fine.

(FWIW, there *is* a port of XBoard to Cocoa - currently named OSXBoard - but it seems to have stalled.)

Answer (score 2):

Jin is the best, also on older macs there was another client "Fixation". I would recommend using a [virtualization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_virtualization) application such as VMWare Fusion or VirtualBox with a Windows guest to run your preferred Windows chess software - as macs also suffer from not having a satisfactory ChessBase client to review games. Performance is not an issue as chess apps do not need be too powerful for these things.

Comment: "satisfactory ChessBase client" is an interesting phrase. Hiarcs and Shredder come full strength on OS/x, as does Stockfish. All three are quite competent analysis engines.

Comment: Arlen - yes, they are not ChessBase clients though, they are analysis engines, which in my view are quite different!

Comment: True, but as there's never been a satisfactory version of ChessBase on the Mac, I didn't see as how the lack of a client for a non-existent entity was by itself a valid criticism. (And yes, CB once tried to make a Mac version, but it was such a slow, buggy hack job no one in their right mind wanted to use it.)

Answer (score 1):

There is now a native quartz xboard.app through GTK2.
http://www.open-aurec.com/wbforum/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=52964

Answer (score 1):

xboard can be installed via [macports](https://www.macports.org/)

```
sudo port install xboard
```

if you run into trouble with your fonts see [XBoard page on wiki.bitplan.com](http://wiki.bitplan.com/index.php/XBoard#MacOS_.2F_macports)